# rbenv init - でエラーが発生します。

Tags: ruby, rbenv, zsh

#### エラー

`$ eval "$(rbenv init -)"`を実行すると以下のようなエラーが発生します

```
(eval):13: parse error near `}'
```

`rbenvv init -` の実行結果です。

```
$ rbenv init -
export PATH="/Users/name/.rbenv/shims:${PATH}"
export RBENV_SHELL=zsh
source '/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.1.2/libexec/../completions/rbenv.zsh'
command rbenv rehash 2>/dev/null
rbenv() {
  local command
  command="${1:-}"
  if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
    shift
  fi

  case "$command" in
  [{ichiro|3}|{jiro|1}|{saburo|2}]|[{jiro|1}|{saburo|2}|{ichiro|3}]) # エラーの出ている13行めです。
    eval "$(rbenv "sh-$command" "$@")";;
  *)
    command rbenv "$command" "$@";;
  esac
}
```

#### 状況

```
$ ls ~/.rbenv/shims
1}       2}       2}]      3}       3}]      [{ichiro [{jiro   {ichiro  {jiro    {saburo
```

```
$ ls ~/.rbenv/
shims    versions # bin directory doesn't exist
```

`pyenv init -` で同じエラーが発生します。

#### 試したこと

rbenv, rbenv-buildのアンインストールおよび再インストール

Comment: OSの情報と、rbenvのインストール方法の追記をお願いできますか？git cloneやhomebrewなど、複数の手段がありますので、そこがわかると回答しやすくなると思います。

Comment: 質問者さんご本人かもしれないアカウントから編集リクエストを頂いていましたが、質問者であれば自分の質問を自由に編集できます。もしアカウントがふたつに分かれてしまった場合、[こちらのページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)を参考にアカウントを統合してから再度お試しくださいませ。

Comment: `shims` フォルダの中に `ruby` も `gem` も無く記号があるのは、想定されていない事態です。pyenv でも同じというのもさらに不思議です。どこを調べたらいいのか見当もつきませんがとりあえず `RBENV_DEBUG=1 rbenv init -` の結果を見せてもらえますか。